# Desaparecen los iconos cuando cambio de vista

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

Tengo un problema con un icono `svg` en `angular-material`, cuando cargo mi pagina el icono carga correctamente con el siguiente código: `<md-icon md-svg-icon="{{ aaa.stat }}" aria-label="Icons Status"></md-icon>` estoy haciendo uso de la imagen mediante un objeto:

```
$scope.aaa = {
        stat: "images/en-espera.svg"
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como pueden ver en la imagen el icono se muestra correctamente, pero cuando voy al home y vuelvo a esta vista el icono parece que se coloque un background transparente...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css"> 
 <title></title>

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular js -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngMaterial']); 
            app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
                $scope.toggleSi = function() {
                $scope.fax = !$scope.fax;
            }

            $scope.aaa = {
                state: "images/en-espera.svg"
            }
        });
        </script>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        
        <md-button class="md-raised|md-fab|md-mini" aria-label="description" ng-click="toggleSi()">MOSTRAR Y OCULTAR</md-button>
        <md-content ng-if="fax">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{ aaa.state }}" aria-label="Alarm Icon"></md-icon>
        </md-content>
    </div>
 

 <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Esto es lo que tengo, estoy usando `angular-material`, para replicar mi error copia y pega el codigo que ingrese y coloca en tu local una `imagen.svg` dentro del objeto `state`

Comment: Pablo, edita tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplo donde se pueda reproducir el error o por lo menos agrega el codigo relevate para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @Einer aun sigo teniendo el problema :(